# Unable to find custom Hive InputFormat when using `where 1=1`

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hadoop2

I'm using Hive and I'm encountering an exception when I'm performing a query with a custom `InputFormat`.

When I use the query `select * from micmiu_blog;` Hive works without problems, but if I use `select * from micmiu_blog where 1=1;` it seems that the framework cannot find my custom `InputFormat` class.

I have put the JAR file into "hive/lib","hadoop/lib" and I have also put "hadoop/lib" into the CLASSPATH. This is the log:

```
hive> select * from micmiu_blog where 1=1;
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1415530028127_0004, Tracking URL = http:/ /hadoop01-master:8088/proxy/application_1415530028127_0004/
Kill Command = /home/hduser/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1415530028127_0004
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2014-11-09 19:53:32,996 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2014-11-09 19:53:52,010 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1415530028127_0004 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Examining task ID: task_1415530028127_0004_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1415530028127_0004

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1415530028127_0004_m_000000

URL:
  http://hadoop01-master:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1415530028127_0004&tipid=task_1415530028127_0004_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.io.IOException: cannot find class hiveinput.MyDemoInputFormat
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:564)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:167)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:162)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:157)


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Job 0: Map: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem just now. You should add your JAR file to the CLASSPATH with hive cli.
You can do it:

```html
hive> add jar /usr/lib/xxx.jar;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try what you say! Finally I solve this problem by putting the JAR file to "$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn", but it is troublesome.